# What does the curl command line tool syntax mean?

Tags: rest, curl

In curl help I see (for example) :

```
-d, --data DATA     HTTP POST data (H)
```

What does the `--data` mean ? Does it mean I can use `-d` **or** `--data` ?

Comment: Please see http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: Yes, exactly; `-d` is short for `--data`. This is conventional CLI design, not specific to curl.